# How to Set Null Value In Text Area

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I want to set null value in onclick() event of textarea, But my code does not work properly..

```
<textarea id="txtwishlistsong1" rows="5" cols="70" runat="server" onclick="return txtwishlistsong1_onclick()">Type Your Message Here...</textarea>
```

code behind

```
function txtwishlistsong1_onclick()
{
   document.getElementById('txtwishlistsong1').focus();
   document.getElementById('txtwishlistsong1').value=null;
}
```

Comment: Why are you putting the code in the code behind and trying to call that? You are performing a client side operation, so just put the function in `<script>`.

Comment: whats problem in this code?

Comment: it works perfectly. whats the problem?

Answer (score 5):

You have your control defined as `runat="server"` to access them in JavaScript you need to specify ClientID.

```
function txtwishlistsong1_onclick()
{
   document.getElementById('<%= txtwishlistsong1.ClientID %>').focus();
   document.getElementById('<%= txtwishlistsong1.ClientID %>').value='';
}
```

Or if you are using .Net framework 4.0 or higher then you may specify `ClientIDMode = "Static"` for the control see more about [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx)

Comment: what is difference between `.value=null` and `.value=""`?

Comment: Why bother with that?...the target `id` is for the element that calls this function `onclick`. Just pass `this` to the function and use `param.focus();` and `param.value = "";`

Answer (score 1):

Set empty value: `""` (not `null`).

According to this [source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLInputElement), value is `DOMString`, and must always have current value of the `input`. Since `input` can't really have `null` value (it's rather abstract in this case), then empty value is better option (and works consistently across browsers).

Answer (score 0):

Likely the reason is asp.net ID mangling.

try using:

```
document.getElementById('<%=txtwishlistsong1.ClientID%>').focus();
document.getElementById('<%=txtwishlistsong1.ClientID%>').value=null;
```